# Can I use a variable resistor to control the heating of a heating element?

Tags: current, resistance, heat

I want to make something that heats up , can I use a variable resistor to control the temperature of the heating element since it is based on current.

Comment: Yes you can in theory, but it's not very practical and you'll waste tons of power doing so.  Your heating element is basically 'a resistor'.  Your variable resistor will probably get as hot (or hotter) than the item you want to control.   There are much better and more practical ways to go about this.   How much power, what's the application, etc???

Comment: Thanks Kyle B.  It's actually a device that is used to heat print on clothes. Usually a bit hotter than pressing irons. What can I use instead?

Comment: So it runs on normal household 110 or 220V AC right???    First thing that pops into mind is a standard light-dimmer (i.e. a "triac" circuit).  You can google "Triac Light Dimmer" well as I can if you wanna understand what they are.  A light bulb is, like your heater, basically a "resistor".  Triacs are ideal for controlling this type of AC load.   If your heater has additional computerized controls, maybe this won't work - but if it's just a coil of hot wire, this will totally work. And you can very easily build one with stuff you buy from the hardware store for maybe $30.

Comment: A low tech (but reasonably efficient solution is to use a variac.

Comment: @Andyaka  Agree that'd be even easier than a triac chopper, but one suitably sized could get pricey.

Comment: You'll spend more time *finding* a Variac than you'll spend building a DIY dimmer circuit.  The one I built for my wife's stained glass setup is just a 2-wide electrical box (North American) with a dimmer on one side and an outlet on the other, and a 3-wire plug coming out the side.

Comment: Thanks. Will try a triac